# Which objectstore is cluster aware?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a requirement of exchanging data between multiple flows. I understand Objectstore will serve for this requirement. 
But my production Server will be a clustered environment.  Came to know that **default Objectstore** is cluster aware.

Now, how to access this particular **default** Objectstore in Mule flows???

Note: currently the Objectstore that I am using is a plugin I downloaded from Anypoint Stack Exchange. Not sure if it is cluster aware or not, as I am not doing any bean configurations for it.

Please help me.

**MOREINFO:**[image]

Here is the Objectstore plugin I am using.  I have downloaded it from the Anypoint Stackexchange    [image]

Comment: Hi, when you talk about echanging data what you mean ? If is just messaging than just use an external mq broker like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ.
If instead you need a shared storage you could use a DB or an object store that persist to file in shared folder. Just keep in mind that if you are going to share a lot of data there is probably a design flaw or you are not using Mule for the right job.

Comment: Here is the scenario. My 'X' Flow has some variable, let us say its value '50'.   Now my  'Y'   flow will receive requests. So, this flow after doing the processing of '50' requests, needs to perform a job. The value of variable is dynamic in nature.  So, i need to control 'Y' flow, based on the variable value in 'X' flow.   So, for this purpose I am using 'ObjectStore'  to store count of no. of requests processed by 'Y' flow.   
I don't this concept to be stored in any queue or file by myself. So, using objectstore concept.
So, I am not sure whether the objectstore I am using is cluster aware

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a centralise shared resource then try creating a Mule Domain, https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources

You would be able to create a shared VM, in which will invoke your common objectstore within a flow.

You will also need to configure a bean of your object store, here is an example:
https://www.ricston.com/blog/cache-scope-ehcache/

That bean will be injected at runtime, or you can inject it by autowiring the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Only when using mule HA in cluster mode (gold commercial offer from mule) I think you can have shared object store, and even there probably not without some tweaks.

An easy way is to make your own object store implementation interfaced with an external or java based cache system like jcs.
This blog post should bring you on the right path

https://dzone.com/articles/synchronizing-data-across-mule